# Getting the joint values of a computed path to a pose goal

Tags: pose, ik, path, joints, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I'm using moveit with an UR5. The planner I use is the RRTConnectkConfigDefault-planner.
The goal for the planner is a pose.

My question is now: Is there a way to retrieve the joint values of the six axes of the computed goal. Maybe out of `my_plan` from `bool success = group.plan(my_plan);`. Maybe something like `moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory = my_plan.trajectory_;`. But I here I got stuck and couldn't find anything in the documentation.

And second: Is there a way to get all possible IK-joints (all IK-solutions which also have no collisions) and choose the goal-joints out of them?

Thanks in advance and regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209548/getting-the-joint-values-of-a-computed-path-to-a-pose-goal/) by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2015-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently use

```
std::vector&lt;double> joints = my_plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.points[plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.points.size()-1].positions;
```

which is kind of stupid because there is also std::vector::back(), so it should be

```
my_plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.points.back().positions
```

Here is the docs you need:

http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/RobotTrajectory.html

http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html

http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectoryPoint.html

so positions is "float64[]" which translates to std::vector<double>

---

Originally posted by [Simon Schmeisser](https://answers.ros.org/users/21773/simon-schmeisser/) with karma: 229 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-05-20**:
This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!
Do you also have by any chance an idea how to get all possible IK-solutions?

**Comment by [Simon Schmeisser](https://answers.ros.org/users/21773/simon-schmeisser/) on 2015-05-20**:
You're welcome. Unfortunately I don't know the answer to your second question. Would be interesting for me as well. I fear this might not be as easy, depending on what IK you use. As far as I understand the default one is sampling/random based and will only find one solution. You could try several

**Comment by [Simon Schmeisser](https://answers.ros.org/users/21773/simon-schmeisser/) on 2015-05-20**:
times and see if it changes? I think that is what some of the code does internally. For ik-fast there might be a way to get all solutions but I don't know it.

Maybe ask on moveit-devel and/or open an extra question?

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-05-26**:
Hi! I asked the question in the moveit-user-google-group. Here is the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/r6O8NO8uNS4).